# How to send $filter query functions on DateTimeOffset values in UI5?

Tags: sapui5, odata-v4

After some Googling, I figured I need the URL to be

```
...$filter=year(DateTimeProperty) eq 1990
```

I am not so sure how to achieve such a filter query using `sap.ui.model.Filter` in UI5.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for how to send the request with `$filter=year(...)` specifically? Or is it more about `$filter` with DateTimeOffset value in general?

Comment: Yes, want the request to be year(date)=1990.

Answer (score -1):

You can create the filter like this:

```
const oFilter = new sap.ui.model.Filter("year", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, "1990");
```

There are multiple ways how to use this filter. If you have an element which is already bound:

```
this.byId("sListId").getBinding("items").filter(oFilter);
```

Obviously you need to adjust the id and binding. Or you can create a new binding where you pass the filter to  the constructor

```
new sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding(oModel, sPath, oContext, vSorters, vFilters, mParameters)
```

Here is the API for OData v4 Listbindings https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.86.0/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding%23methods/filter and here is some documention about filter and OData V4 https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.86.0/#/topic/426ff318051a465191c861b51a74f00e

Comment: I actually want to filter only on year part of a date or datetimeoffset column